# How to get the dynamic id in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php  
  while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      <strong>Recieved Date:</strong>
      <input style="width:70px;" id="rec_date" class="rec_dat" 
             type="text" name="payment_recieved_date">;
  }
?>
```

And my javascript function is:

```
 $(function() {
    $(".rec_date").datepicker();
    $('.rec_date').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 
       "yy-m-d" + " " + getCurrentTime());

        //datepicker({dateFormat: '<?php echo "yy-m-d"; ?>', 
        //   changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '-100:+0'});
    });
```

I have a problem that calendar is showing and add value for first iteration and the second just showing calendar but no value is added when I select the date.

Please guide me to make id unique at javascript function.

Comment: I don't see how the calendar would show at all, as the JavaScript code is using a different class than you're outputting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're outputting multiple elements with the same `id` value. That's invalid, and (I just checked) it's confusing the jQuery UI `datepicker`.

If you remove the `id`s, and output the class as `rec_date` (not `rec_dat`) on the elements, it works correctly:

```js
$(".rec_date").datepicker();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" class="rec_date">
<input type="text" class="rec_date">
<input type="text" class="rec_date">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```